# Accept --not revisions from standard input for git bundle

Tags: git

I wish to run a git bundle creation command where the list of revisions to be excluded using the `--not` switch has to come from a file.

The command I am running needs to be equivalent to `git bundle create /path/to/mybundle --all --tags --not <rev_1> <rev_2> ... <rev_N>`. But the list of revisions `<rev_1>`, `<rev_2>` and so on need to come from a file that has these revisions one on each line.

I am on the latest git version - `git version 2.42.0.windows.1`, as there were some changes made in this version about the `--stdin` switches behavior.

So far I have tried running `echo "$(cat ../revlisttoexclude.txt)" | git bundle create /path/to/bundle --all --not --stdin`, but it ends up including all revisions and doesn't exclude any revision from the ones provided in the file.

Any idea how can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Side note: instead of `echo "$(cat file)" | whatever` just do `whatever <file`.

Answer (score 2):

rev-list's `--stdin` processing seems to ignore the `--not` option. (rev-list is one of Git's everything-uses-this-under-the-hood bits). Whether that's as it should be is debatable, my first reaction is "what? why? why do that?", and if whether changing it now is a good move would be another debate, but there's an easy workaround.

You can fix it by using the exclude prefix, if you want to leave your excludes list untouched do

```
sed s,^,^, ../revlisttoexclude.txt | git bundle etc --stdin
```

where the first `^` is the match-start-of-line op and the second is a literal `^`, which Git will interpret as "exclude this and its ancestors".

Comment: Wow, this works like a charm! I am holding off on marking this as an answer just in case someone adds more comments, but will do so in a day or two! Thanks again!

Comment: I would instead say that this is not a bug, as the `--stdin` option says "take all refs from stdin and ignore the command-line refs, including the `--not`". The `--not` option is only to negate the refs that appear later in the command line. Adding `^` in front of the lines you want to negate is the proper way to do this. (You can also have lines without `^` if you wanted custom starting points.)

Comment: @DerrickStolee My install and [the current docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---stdin) do not say that, I see it was changed to allow more general options in c40f0b7 just a couple months ago.